# Jenkins and Gitlab don't fetch code

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have a problem when i set my own project.
I start to configure my Jenkins Job, and I done this:

- create credential on Jenkins for gitlab user account
- create access token on gitlab and use this token in Jenkins to enable it

[image]

and this is the job configuration
[image]

but when i start a build, after10 minutes i get this error

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/xxxxxxxxx
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.xxxxxxxxx.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://xxxxxxxx.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress https://xxxxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://gitlab.xxxxxxx.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:825)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1092)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1123)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.matrix.MatrixBuild.run(MatrixBuild.java:314)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress https://xxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1970)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1689)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:380)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:823)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

So... how do i solve this?

Comment: *ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes* check your proxy config or raise the timeout value if  your repo is really big

Comment: have some hints from here? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36269 , the issue reporter solved his problem via adding his gitlab URL to proxy exception

Comment: @JoaoVitorino i don't think it's a really "timeout" problem, but something about connection from jenkins and gitlab

Comment: @V-SHY i'm checking now! thanks

Comment: @V-SHY Ok, I read your hint, but we don't have a proxy!!! Also, if i use, from shell, git clone from same machine (where jenkins is installed) and same repository url, that's works!!!

Comment: jenkins is running as service?

Comment: @JoaoVitorino yes of course. Still working on Apple machine

Answer (score 1):

I think to solve the question. Follow this guide to add and enable jenkins user http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/

and, at the moment, works. Thanks all

Comment: link seems to be dead !

Comment: @Zaknafein how did you solve this? facing same issue

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora have you follow the guidelines i suggest in this answer?

Comment: Maybe this is the active link for the SETTING UP JENKINS USER in mac
https://medium.com/@ved.pandey/setting-up-jenkins-on-mac-osx-50d8fe16df9f

Answer (score 0):

Check this option "Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations" under "Advanced Clone Behaviors"
Default time-out is 10min.

Comment: i think not a timetout error... i think it's other stuff

Comment: Did you try out the steps I mentioned? Does error persist even after that?

Comment: persist, but i have news... I'm onpening a new thread ;) thanks